# Visual Studio Project restore old version

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, restore

I am working on an ASP.NET web project in Visual Studio 2013 and it worked couple of hours before. But an hour ago I was tweaking something in the project and messed up the entire project. Is there anyway to restore to the version I had yesterday?

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but are you using source control? Or maybe if you're using Windows 8 and you happened to turn on the File History feature, you might be in luck: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/how-use-file-history

Comment: I dont use source control and the windows 8 file history is off. Oh well, maybe i can start over the project.

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware, there are many great free source control systems out there that tie into VS nicely. For private projects, I prefer visualstudio.com. For public/open source projects, I prefer github.com.

Comment: I do use visualstudio.com but do they have project history?

Comment: I don't understand how in one sentence you said you don't use source control, but four hours ago you said you use visualstudio.com.

Comment: I didn't know visualstudio.com count as source control

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Version control, such as Mercurial, GIT, Subversion, TFS -- **and** you remembered to commit your work then YES, definitely.

If you're not using Version Control then you need to ask yourself why not? And don't turn off the computer today until you've corrected that oversight.

Also, you may have previous versions/restore points saved for you in Windows. In windows explorer, right click on the folder where your work is being saved and select properties. They may be a 'previous versions' tab, and inside there you may be able to revert to an earlier version. If so: lucky lucky you.

Also, if your work is being shared using a service like DropBox, you will be able to find earlier versions of your solution or project files.

There is one other technique, and I... I hesitate to mention this. What you need is a DeLorean car from the eighties, and enough plutonium to generate 1 point 21 GigaWatts. You also need.... forget it, no, Version Control is your best bet. Or **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>**.

Answer (score 3):

Holding **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>** for a few minutes, and using version control are the only two ways I am aware of doing that..

Answer (score 0):

In case you're like me and trying to recover from what you just did, if you saved your work to OneDrive, you can find the previous version of your work by logging into OneDrive through a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Visual Studio should have a **"Timeline"** feature that shows up in your left bar. It has probably been saving past versions of your files. But I would agree with others that using Version Control (like just committing your changes to a Github repo) is probably a smart idea!