# All control dissapears (Form become empty) VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have 1 form with the name frmMain, then I create the form again and by accident I named my new form to frmMain, then I change the name of my new form it into FrmSecond, then when I tried to open the frmMain I got the error to go into frmMain designer, then I click "ignore and continue" then frmMain be empty .. all textbox or label and others became lost. Then I delete FrmSecond and I closed my project without saving and I open my project again, but still the same frmMain remains empty, but the code list is still there. how can i resolve this? thanks.

this code before create FrmSecond..

```
Private Sub FrmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

this code after create FrmSecond..

```
Private Sub FrmMain_Load_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

the different is "Handles MyBase.Load" and "FrmMain_Load" become "FrmMain_Load_1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you build/run the project, the files are saved.

So unless you have source control or can restore the folder in Windows (not reliable to say the least), then you're probably screwed.

Previous answer to a question like this:
[Visual Studio Project restore old version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004496/visual-studio-project-restore-old-version)

My advice is if you try the folder restore with Windows, back up the folder elsewhere before doing so.

Alternatively, you can just rebuild your form since all of the functionality is still there.

Before doing anything, check in your project folder in explorer and open up each one of your forms (and the one(s) you deleted in the Recycling Bin). Manually open them up and see if your UI still exists.

Comment: LOL..i never delete my FrmMain, but i dont know why my FrmMain.Designer.vb is in Recycle Bin, so i restore and my control or object become visible again.. but i need to make a litle change like "Private Sub BtnInsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)" become  "Private Sub BtnInsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnInsert.Click" thanks.

Comment: Excellent. Glad I could help. It always sucks having to redo work.